# return if it contains value from yesterday

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
id  bigint  
phone_number    text
account_id  bigint
used    boolean
insert_timestamp    timestamptz
```

I want to get results if `used = false` and if the id of `account_id` contains at least one id inserted from yesterday or older.

for example we have the following rows

```
 id     phone_numberaccount_id  used    insert_timestamp
 7292   16360000000 1093630     f       2018-04-10 12:48:17.700558-04
 7293   16360000000 1093630     f       2018-04-10 12:48:17.700558-04
 7294   16360000000 1093630     f       2018-04-10 12:48:17.700558-04
 7295   16360000000 1093630     f       2018-04-11 12:48:17.700558-04
 7296   16360000000 1093631     f       2018-04-11 12:48:17.700558-04
```

The query should return 7292, 7293, 7294 and 7295  but not 7296 because there is not one with the account_id of 1093631 from yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE account_id IN (SELECT account_id
                     FROM tab
                     WHERE inserted_timestamp < now()::date
                    AND used = false);
```

Comment: This would return any row that has the date older than inserted time. It does not check to see if one exists related to the account_id.

Comment: How would we change this to at least 15 hours instead of a full day?